# Remove Directory name from URL in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

My url looks something like this http:www.example.com/subdirectory  . Code is present in this sub directory . I want that my app runs at http:www.example.com . I have tried multiple rewrite rules in .htaccess file . How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by changing routes.php in config folder

add this to your routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "subdirectory/home";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['subdirectory'] = "subdirectory/home";
$route['subdirectory/(:any)'] = "subdirectory/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule in root `.htaccess` (a level above sub directory):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!subdirectory/).*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: i have added this rule , but no effect , i cannot access my app at www.example.com

Comment: Add a `R` flag in above to make it `RewriteRule ^((?!subdirectory/).*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L,NC,R]` and enter `www.example.com` in your browser.